# Trying to access a file on a USB drive not using a drive letter

Tags: windows, usb, unc

Is this possible in Windows ?

In OSX I can go to /Volumes/Usbvol/Thisdir .

Can i navigate to the USB volume without using the assigned drive letter?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/295913/how-to-mount-and-unmount-hard-drives-under-windows-the-unix-way/295915#295915). And *please* explain **why** you need this.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, this is generally not possible unless you've mounted the drive at a non-standard location.

It is possible to mount drives within one another starting with Windows 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this? If it's because the drive letter changes and you're trying to access it across sessions, you can manually set it to something high like R: or Z: so that it won't be re-used by going to Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Storage -> Disk Management and then right clicking on the drive and clicking Change Drive Letter and Paths.

Comment: I've written a javascript app that accesses files on the USB drive ... obviously if i plug it into another computer the drive letter may change.

Comment: You could assign the USB drive to A or B.  These drive letters - particularly B - are available on almost every modern computer and aren't auto-assigned by Windows.   Once you assign one of these letters to a USB drive, the drive will use the same letter when removed and reinserted.

Comment: @boomshanka is the javascript app running from the flashdrive? If so, can't you use relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is consistent when you remove and re-add the device, but this might be helpful:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321.aspx